# Como realizar uma transition de "volta" utilizando o Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, css-transições, vue-router, transição

Estou fazendo uma transição simples em um webapp (utilizando animate.css), onde o usuário clica em um botão e o componente atual sai da tela pela esquerda e o outro componente vem da direita para esquerda. Porém quando eu retorno para o meu componente inicial, a transição não faz o caminho contrário.

Como posso realizar isso? Existe alguma propriedade na transition do Vue para que ele realize o caminho contrário?

Exemplo das propriedades abaixo:

```
<transition name="router-anim" leave-active-class="animated slideOutLeft faster" enter-active-class="animated slideInRight faster" mode="out-in">
   <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

Comment: Está usando alguma biblioteca de transições ou você mesmo fez suas transições? Se é você mesmo que fez, você poderia postar o CSS também.

Comment: estou utilizando o animate.css mas independente da animação eu não consigo acertar a ordem de "ida" e "volta" dela

Comment: Entendo, é para facilitar o nosso entendimento do seu problema... Poderia ter alguma coisa errada com seu CSS, mas já dá pra ver que não é o caso.
Se você puder, adicione na pergunta que você está usando o animate.css

Comment: Cara, fiz [esse JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gvtkxa4/) e nele está funcionando a animação, tanto clicando nas rotas quanto usando `history.back()`

Comment: o meu problema é que se tu reparar a animação sempre vem da direita para a esquerda, quando eu clicasse no "back" era pra ir no sentido contrário

Comment: Entendi, mas aí teria que ter uma estrutura pra saber quando uma rota estaria voltando, pra depois inverter as classes do transition... o buraco é mais embaixo mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Tem [esse](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/transitions/app.js) exemplo no próprio repositório que como é possível fazer isso. Você precisa passar a animação dinamicamente atráves de uma propriedade. Para definir qual animação usar e quando usar você pode usar a função "beforeRouteUpdate" e comparar o "to" com o "from".
Segue abaixo um pequeno exemplo baseado no link acima.

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    this.transitionName = to.path === "rota2" ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
    next()
}
```